# Select an option in a menu doesn't work (html DOM)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a IE page containing this code:   (I simplified it for this post)

```
<select class="form-control" id="areaSelect" onchange="blur()">
     <option value="uno" selected="">Uno</option>
     <option value="due" selected="">Due</option>
     <option value="tre" selected="">Tre</option>
</select>

<input id="srch-term"></input>
```

With the following command I can set the text of the input to "foobar": (it works!)

```
.getElementById("srch-term").value = "foobar"
```

while with the following code nothing happens:

```
.getElementById("areaSelect").click     ' (it doesn't work: nothing happens)
.getElementById("areaSelect").value = "due"   ' (it doesn't work: nothing happens)
```

Even in the IE console the last two commands don't work, giving no error and no effect.

Why?
What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text area is different from a drop-down list. To change the option you must choose the needed index and trigger the change event. You can do it like this:

```
'Needed variable
Dim nodeAreaSelect As Object

'Your code
'...

'Select "Due" from drop-down list
Set nodeAreaSelect = .getElementByID("areaSelect")
nodeAreaSelect.selectedIndex = 1 'Index from 0 to 2 in your example. Index 1 for "Due"
'Trigger change event of the drop-down list
Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeAreaSelect, "change") 'Change browser.document to your html document

'The rest of your code
'...
```

And this procedure to trigger the event:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! you saved me big headaches :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want, do you want to change text of input as same value of select ?
please explain better.

Comment: Don't place comments as an answer.

Comment: My goal is to select an option of the "areaSelect" menu